# Render a component based on its value

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code, I want to render the `by{' '} <UserInfo />` part only if `<UserInfo />` returns a value and not an empty string

```
<Typography>
   Updated {item.updatedAt} ago, by{' '}
   <UserInfo userId={item.updatedBy } />
</Typography>
```

How do I do that?

```
export default function UserInfo({userId}) {   
    const {useGet} = useApi()
    const {data: userInfo} = useGet(`/users/${userId}`)
    const [lastName, firstName] = userInfo?.data.displayName?.split(',') || ''
    const userName = firstName && lastName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : userInfo?.data.displayName    
  return <span>{userName}</span>
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if <UserInfo /> returns a value"? UserInfo is a component, it will always return ```<span>{userName}</span>```. However, if you want to render ```<UserInfo/>``` based in a property from the object "item", you could replace ```<UserInfo/>``` with ```{item.exists && <UserInfo />}```. That way ```<UserInfo/>``` will not be rendered if ```exists``` is false.

Comment: Do you mean *only if `userName` has a value*?  If that's the case then your outer component would need to see that value.  Whatever "logic to get user" is, that would be moved to the main component and the results can be passed to `<UserInfo>` as a prop.  Or both could pull `userName` from the same global state (context?  Redux?  something else?).

Comment: The `<UserInfo>` component is being used many times so I do not want to make changes to it. There is no way to check if the component returned a not empty string value? @David?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> only if `<UserInfo />` returns a value

That's the wrong approach, for a couple of reasons.  Firstly, it doesn't make much sense to check if a component *itself* "returns a value".  Second, your component *always* "returns a value":

```
return <span>{userName}</span>
```

It sounds like the value you want to check is `userName`.  So you'll want to move that logic out of the `<UserInfo>` component, either into this parent component (often called "lifting state up") or into some more global location (a global state management system like Redux, a hook like `useContext`, etc.).

For example, suppose you move that logic into a custom hook.  Then each of these components can use that hook:

```
export default function UserInfo({userId}) {   
  const {userName} = useUserName();
  return <span>{userName}</span>;
}
```

And in the parent component:

```
// somewhere above the JSX
const {userName} = useUserName();

// then within the JSX
<Typography>
  Updated {item.updatedAt} ago
  { userName ? <>, by <UserInfo userId={item.updatedBy } /></> : null }
</Typography>
```

The implementation for `useUserName` would be [a new custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) which performs the same logic it does within the `<UserInfo>` component now and exposes the result of that logic.  The benefit here is that now any component can observe that `userName` value (and any other "user" value you want to expose).

---

An *untested* example of such a custom hook might be...

```
function useUserName(friendID) {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // your exact logic for getting the username...
    const {useGet} = useApi();
    const {data: userInfo} = useGet(`/users/${userId}`);
    const [lastName, firstName] = userInfo?.data.displayName?.split(',') || '';
    const userName = firstName && lastName ? `${firstName} ${lastName}` : userInfo?.data.displayName;

    // then...
    setUserName(userName);
  }, []);

  return { userName };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is:

add `by{' '}` in the userInfo return and you need to put a condition in `<userInfo/>` while returning JSX from `<userInfo/>` if it's returning something then prepend `by{' '}` in its return block and in the else part of the condition return null.

note:- null doesn't render on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary condition to make the conditional rendering, for example:

```
return(
 ... // other components
  {
    userInfo.value && (
           by{' '}
       <UserInfo />
      )
  }
)
```

Follow the link of React Docs with these solution: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the `userInfo.value`...

Comment: The equivalent of userInfo.value is the infos of user, actually you make these verification in <UserInfo /> component, you need to make these in dad component and  pass props to the children, example

... //Get user Infos

return(

<Typography>
   Updated {item.updatedAt} ago, by{' '}
  **{ userInfos && 
   <UserInfo userInfos={userInfos} />
  }**
</Typography>)

With these you have your info in component and can pass these with props for children